# Jmeter - How can we calculate think time from response time?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Suppose, I am adding some think time(Timers) in each HTTP request, but when I execute the test, in the report it shows response time as Sum of ThinkTime + actual response time.

How can I get actual response time from the result?

Answer (score 3):

by default, JMeter does not include Timer's time in the response time of any HTTP sampler.

In case if you are using Transaction Controller to group the requests, then you can deselect the checkbox `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` in the transaction controller.

Answer (score 3):

By default JMeter **does not include** the duration of:

- [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)
- [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

into Sampler's response time unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) with `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` option selected. If this is the case and you use dynamic values in the Timer - you can consider using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) functionality to record think time into .jtl results file.

Answer (score 1):

*Think Time* is the time taken by the user to read,
understand and take next action on the webpage.

So the time between a response and the next request
is the *Think Time*. This can be simulated by adding
a timer.